# Kivy: pass latency and drop-on-latency arguments to GstPlayer video streaming widget

Tags: python, overriding, kivy, cython, gstreamer

I am looking to extend the functionality of `Kivy's` Video widget.

When playing an `RTSP` video stream using the following `Kivy` code, there is latency of a few seconds. I would like to reduce the latency to around `100ms`.

videostreaming.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os.path

path_to_kv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'videostreaming.kv')
Builder.load_file(path_to_kv)


class VideoStreaming(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widg = VideoStreaming()
        return root_widg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

videostreaming.kv:

```
<VideoStreaming>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Video:
        source: "rtsp://192.168.1.88:554"
        state: 'play'
```

The low latency required can be achieved in Command Prompt by running:

```
$ .\gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.1.88:554 drop-on-latency=true latency=100
```

I would like to modify the behavior of the `GstPlayer` video module in Kivy to allow the "drop-on-latency=true" and "latency=100" arguments to be passed in.

The relevant Kivy source code is here: 
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blame/master/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx#L237-L256

**Q1.** How can I subclass the GstPlayer Cython module to include access to the latency and drop-on-latency arguments?

I think that the subclass should override the load() method as follows:

```
# import GstPlayer module to be subclassed
from kivy.lib.gstplayer cimport GstPlayer

# define subclass
cdef class LowLatencyGst(GstPlayer):

    #override load() method
    def load(self):
        # run parent's load() method
        super(LowLatencyGst, self).load()

        # set required attributes: latency = 100, drop-on-latency = True
        # Unconfirmed whether these commands are correctly named
        g_object_set_int(self.appsink, 'latency', 100)
        g_object_set_int(self.appsink, 'drop-on-latency', 1)
```

Note: Trying to compile the above code is unsuccessful. It is pseudocode.

**Q2.** How can I integrate the above subclass as the CoreVideo provider for a Video widget?

Answer (score 0):

The following commit provides a hardcoded solution to specifying latency and drop-on-latency values:
https://github.com/sabarlow/kivy/commit/846e3147db4ac784c1aa4d02f47666716fb57644

Added following lines of code to \kivy\lib\gstplayer_gstplayer.pyx:265

```
g_object_set_int(self.pipeline, 'drop-on-latency', self.drop_on_latency)
g_object_set_int(self.pipeline, 'latency', self.latency)
```

Setup with \kivy\lib\gstplayer_gstplayer.pyx:184

```
cdef int latency, drop_on_latency
```

And in same file:

```
def __init__(self, uri, sample_cb=None, eos_cb=None, message_cb=None, latency=500, drop_on_latency=1):
        super(GstPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.uri = uri
        self.sample_cb = sample_cb
        self.eos_cb = eos_cb
        self.message_cb = message_cb
        self.latency = latency
        self.drop_on_latency = drop_on_latency
```

Then Kivy is recompiled.

This does not allow values for latency and drop-on-latency to be passed in from Kivy's Video widget. Can anyone suggest how to make this work?